# Where clause is not working in php code

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

When I am checking `project_id` also record is not deleting.here i want to delete a particular record which has specified project_id and beneficiary_id.This code is working only for beneficiary_id checking

```
 **In model**
  public function get_real_beneficiary($id,$project_id) {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('projects_beneficiaries');
  $this->db->where('beneficiary_id', $id);
  //$this->db->where('project_id', $project_id);

  $query = $this->db->get();
  echo $this->db->last_query();
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->row();
  }
  else return FALSE;
}

public function delete_beneficiary($id) {
  $sa = $this->ion_auth->in_group(array(ROLE_SUPERADMIN));
  $ad = $this->ion_auth->in_group(array(ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR));
  $ma = $this->ion_auth->in_group(array(ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER));
  /* Verify */
  if($sa || $ad || $ma){
    return $this->db->delete('projects_beneficiaries', array('id' => $id));
  }
  else return FALSE;
}

**In controller-delete action**
public function delete($id){
  $bn = $this->Beneficiaries_model->get_real_beneficiary($this->uri->segment(4),
   $this->uri->segment(5));
    // log_message('error',$bn->project_id );
  $this->Beneficiaries_model->delete_beneficiary($bn->id);
   // log_message('error','Project Id:'$this->uri->segment(5) );
  redirect('projects/view/' . $this->uri->segment(5));
}
```

`beneficiary_id` is present for different projects.If I am not checking `project_id` all related 
records are deleting. How can I delete specified record?

Comment: make it clear what you want to say

Comment: Your question is vague. Please clarify more.

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); to check the SQL below  $query = $this->db->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the problem is i am not getting current project_id.Now i am able to get the project id from view.Thank you who tries to help me.